# silverlight binding grid column from a comboBox using xaml element Binding

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to add a unbound column to a a xamgrid but I want to get the value from a combox, the combobox is bound to channel object at runtime.

I tried adding the unbound column.

Tried:

```
<Binding  Source="{StaticResource  ChannelTemplate}" Path="SelectedItem.Content"   />
```

But it doesn't seem to work
I want to bind the channelcode to the grid.

Grid,class code below.

```
 <UI:BaseControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="ChannelTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=ChannelName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
 </UI:BaseControl.Resources>

<ComboBox Name="CboChannel" Margin="59,6,0,0" Height="22" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChannelTemplate}" >
</ComboBox>

<ig:XamGrid Name="grdInventory" ColumnWidth="auto" ....
 <ig:XamGrid.Columns>
<ig:UnboundColumn Key="Channel">
                    <ig:UnboundColumn.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >                          
         <TextBlock >
                                <TextBlock.Text >
                                    <Binding  Source="{StaticResource  ChannelTemplate}" Path="SelectedItem.Content"   />
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>                
                        </DataTemplate>
              </ig:UnboundColumn.ItemTemplate> 
</ig:UnboundColumn> 
</ig:XamGrid.Columns>
</ig:XamGrid>
```

Code:

```
Public Class Channel
    Implements IDisposable

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=True)>
    Public Property ChannelID As Long

     <DataMember()>
    Public Property ChannelDescription As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ChannelName As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ChannelCode As String
End Class
```

Thanks 
J

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a DataContext pattern so that your unbound column and combobox selected item are both bound to the same value.  For example (I'm using the standard data grid here):

1) Create a DataContextProxy class based on this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx

2) Create a static resource to the DataContextProxy on the page that contains the grid and combo e.g.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Silverlight:DataContextProxy x:Key="Proxy"></Silverlight:DataContextProxy>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

3) Bind the SelectedValue property of your combo to an exposed property on your VM e.g.

```
<ComboBox Height="23"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          SelectedValue="{Binding TestProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Content"
          Margin="126,54,0,0" x:Name="comboBox1"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="Content">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="x" Content="test2"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="x2" Content="test"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

4) Bind the grid column template to the same VM property e.g.

```
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  Height="120"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="155,153,0,0"
                  Name="dataGrid1"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">            
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Source={StaticResource Proxy},Path=DataSource.TestProperty}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>  
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

This worked for me when I knocked up a quick test app.  The DataGridTemplateColumn stays in sync with the selected combobox item.